# The element type 'List<Card>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't understand how can we use the column widget after removing the square brackets[] from the children. I wanted to create a list of cards from a list of string elements. I used the map method to do so.

I was using the map method inside the column widget and it constantly showed the error `The element type 'List<Card>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'`. I solved it by wrapping the flights.map((element){}) inside another column widget and then removing the [] of the children.

```
Column(
              children:[ flights.map(
                    (element) => Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('images/flight.jfif'),
                      Text(element)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ).toList(),]
            )
          ],
)
```

**afterwards**

```
Column(
              children: flights.map(
                    (element) => Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('images/flight.jfif'),
                      Text(element)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ).toList(),
            )
          ],
        )
```

The first code snippet shows the error that The element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

The second one does not show any error

Comment: yes. That is the question. Why are they redundant? I am a beginner and till now everytime I used column widget, I used to put those after children. Does it mean, I am creating a list within another list, or something of this sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *children* requires list of widgets. But in your first case it is getting list of list because **flights.map** will return list of Card widgets. so it becomes like,

```
Column(
       children:[ []
    ],
)
```

But in second case, *children* is getting only list of widgets that's what it needed. So it becomes,

```
Column(
       children: []  
)
```

which is right format.